# Database transaction read uncommitted

Tags: sql, database, transactions

I have one question about transactions. Hope it is not a duplicate, I've been searching for some time and I found nothing useful. So, I recently learned about **`database transactions`** and **`read uncommitted`**.

Can a transaction(or a simple query) reads some dirty data from a **`DML`** instruction that is still running?

For example, I have a table R(A) with tuples ({1},{2}) and two transactions:

```
T1: UPDATE R SET A=A*2;
T2: SELECT AVG(R) FROM R;
```

We assume that **`T2 ISOLATION LEVEL`** is **`READ UNCOMMITTED`**.

Is there any possibility that **`T2`** will read dirty data from **`T1`**, even if it's not over? Le's say that T1 updated in the moment of the execution of **`T2`** only the first **`tuple`**(R becoming now ({2},{2} or ({1},{4}))?

How does a transaction executes in situations like this?

Comment: Did you mean AVG(A)? Are T1 and T2 different transactions?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? Not all database actually support read UNcommitted.

Comment: Yeah, I typed wrong, AVG(A) is what I wanted. And yes, they are different transactions.

Comment: Just learning about transactions in general, no DBMS at all, just wanted knowledge about this topic.

Comment: Well, the DBMS is important. Some implementations will return wrong results even with read committed in that situations.

Comment: Well, I'm a student and this is a topic over the courses. I read in parallel a book(A First Course in Database System) and it didn't helped me with my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you use MS SQL, then you can use NOLOCK:

```
SELECT AVG(A) FROM R (NOLOCK);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my question. I was thinking that the when read uncommitted, my statements could interfere one with another in time of execution of one statement(for e.g, value of A updated only in first tuple, T2 execute and after that the second tuple is updated) and I found that read uncommitted allows interference after a statement(not all statements from a transaction) has executed.